# uwsgi socket permissions

Tags: uwsgi

I'm running into some permission issues with uwsgi running on Ubuntu 12. Here is my ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
project = djangorpoject
base_dir = /home/mysite/mysite.com

uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins = http,python

processes = 4
harakiri = 60
reload-mercy = 8
cpu-affinity = 1
max-requests =  2000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
no-orphans = True
#vacuum = True
master = True

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
#daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
#catch-exceptions
disable-logging

virtualenv = %(base_dir)/venv
chdir = %(base_dir)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

socket = /run/uwsgi/%n.sock
chmod-socket = 666
chown-socket = www-data:www-data
```

As you can see, I am running chmod and chown on the socket file. When I attempt to load my site, I am getting the following error:

```
bind(): Permission denied [socket.c line 107]
```

This goes away if I run

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /run/uwsgi
```

But this doesn't persist when I reboot my server. I am assuming this is because uwsgi is recreating the folder on boot? Is there any way to permanently apply the permissions to socket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/run` is a `tmpfs` which means it is not persistent across reboots. Create a directory `/var/uwsgi` instead which will be persistent.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work either. /var/run appears to be identical to /run, are they symlinked?

Comment: @Hanpan, you are right I should've checked. I've edited the answer.